# Image stacking with info options hover

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

Basically I have a dynamic image with stacking of another image/"effect" on top.

That part is working fine.

But when I go to `span:hover` + `div` for a user options area on top of the combined images it mostly works with the hover affect, but the hovered item seems to flash on mouseover.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.stack {
      position: absolute;
      left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      z-index: -2;
  }

div {
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
    align-items: center;
    top: 5px;
    display: none;
}

span:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td class='#jail' style='position:relative'>
   <span><img src='/{$ir['display_pic']}' class='stack'>
         <img src='/overlay.png' class='stack'>
   </span>
   <div>
    <center>
     <a href='http://'>Option 1</a>
     <br />
     <a href='http://'>Option 2</a>
    </center>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want a hover effect that gradually shows it instead of it just snapping straight away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you are asking for. It's a fade in on hover.

Note the changes I removed

```
span:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

and replaced it with the class .hovered and .hovered:hover

Hope this helps,

Tim

```css
.stack {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -2;
}

.hovered {
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    align-items: center;
    top: 5px;
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
}

.hovered:hover {
  opacity: 1;    
          transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in; /* vendorless fallback */
       -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in; /* Opera */
      -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in; /* IE 10 */
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in; /* Safari & Chrome */
}
```

```html
<table border="0">
 <tr>
  <td class='#jail' style='position:relative'>
   <span><img src='<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000">' class='stack'>
         <img src='<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00">' class='stack'>
   </span>
   <div class="hovered">
    <center>
     <a href='http://'>Option 1</a>
     <br />
     <a href='http://'>Option 2</a>
    </center>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```